# ipmitool and freeipmi don't see the same sensors

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

i have many servers from different manufacturers and have a already working script for hardware health monitoring using freeipmi on Redhat 7.6.

Now i have a new HP ProLiant DL560 Gen10 machine where the output of freeipmi looks like this:

```
root@machine ~ # ipmi-sensors -t "Power_Supply"
ID  | Name           | Type         | Reading    | Units | Event
102 | Power Supply 1 | Power Supply | N/A        | N/A   | N/A
103 | PS 1 Output    | Power Supply | N/A        | W     | N/A
104 | Power Supply 2 | Power Supply | N/A        | N/A   | N/A
105 | PS 2 Output    | Power Supply | N/A        | W     | N/A
106 | Power Supply 3 | Power Supply | N/A        | N/A   | N/A
107 | PS 3 Output    | Power Supply | N/A        | W     | N/A
108 | Power Supply 4 | Power Supply | N/A        | N/A   | N/A
109 | PS 4 Output    | Power Supply | N/A        | W     | N/A
111 | Power Supplies | Power Supply | N/A        | N/A   | N/A
```

Freeipmi cannot see the status of the power supplies, ipmitool can see it:

```
root@machine ~ # ipmitool sdr type "Power Supply"
Power Supply 1   | 32h | ok  | 10.1 | Presence detected
PS 1 Output      | 3Ah | ok  | 10.1 | 185 Watts
Power Supply 2   | 33h | ok  | 10.2 | Presence detected, Failure detected, Power Supply AC lost
PS 2 Output      | 3Bh | ok  | 10.2 | 0 Watts
Power Supply 3   | 34h | ok  | 10.3 | Presence detected
PS 3 Output      | 3Ch | ok  | 10.3 | 55 Watts
Power Supply 4   | 35h | ok  | 10.4 | Presence detected, Failure detected, Power Supply AC lost
PS 4 Output      | 3Dh | ok  | 10.4 | 0 Watts
Power Supplies   | 42h | ok  | 19.1 | Fully Redundant
```

Why are the power supply sensors not available in freeipmi while they are available in ipmitool? The problem exists for other types like Fans or Drives. Are the tools both use different ways to get information from BMC?

kind regards,
Goetz

Comment: I see the same issue for all sensors, such as `fans`: `68  | Fan 1 DutyCycle  | Fan                      | N/A      | N/A        | %           | N/A        | N/A        | N/A        | N/A        | N/A        | N/A        | N/A` vs `ipmitool`: `Fan 1 DutyCycle  | 12.936     | percent    | ok    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na` on `ProLiant DL380 Gen10`. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: I just found out that `--bridge-sensors` help: `ipmi-sensors --bridge-sensors`. "Some sensors may have a sensor reading or sensor event of "N/A" if the information is unavailable. This is typical of a sensor that is not enabled or not owned by a BMC. Please see --bridge-sensors option below to deal with sensors not owned by a BMC" from the man pages

Comment: Hi hudac, thanks for your comment. The Event-States changed from 'N/A' to 'OK' or 'Fully Redundant'. The values in reading column appeared also.  This is a solution! Please place your comment as an answer so i can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that `--bridge-sensors` helps (`ipmi-sensors --bridge-sensors`).
From the man pages:

> Some sensors may have a sensor reading or sensor event of "N/A" if the information is unavailable. This is typical of a sensor that is not enabled or not owned by a BMC. Please see --bridge-sensors option below to deal with sensors not owned by a BMC

Answer (score 3):

FreeIPMI maintainer here.  Please try the workaround flag "-W discretereading" for ipmi-sensors.  HP motherboards have a well known issue where they define a large number of sensors illegally.  It's also possible other workaround flags may help as well, you can find a list in the ipmi-sensors manpage.

Comment: i have tried with descretereading flag on, the same output occured. I also tried other flags from manpage where HP is named, always the same result.

Comment: Perhaps HP has a new issue we have to work around, can you bring up issue on the freeipmi mailing list and we can iterate over it.  Thanks.

Comment: Was it ever issued?
Is there a solution for it?